# Method inheritance for Core Data Entities (one's the parent)

Tags: ios, core-data, inheritance, methods

I have 3 entities with one being the parent of the other two. I have created NSManagedObject subclasses for each of them. I know how to inherit the attributes from the parent class but I need to inherit a method. Right now I only have 1 view controller so I really have no clue how I can do method inheritance with just one VC, or can I? All 3 entities will have a method with the same name. Thank you for any possible help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but please rewrite your question.  I can't tell what it is that you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a method in your parent class, and override it in the child classes:

```
@interface BaseClass : NSManagedObject
- (void)doSomething;
@end

@interface InheritedClass : BaseClass
- (void)doSomething;
@end

@implementation InheritedClass
- (void)doSomething {
    [super doSomething];
    ....
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks! So the "don't touch the classes created for your entities" I read everywhere is overlooked when needing to accomplish this task?

Comment: The reason they say "don't touch the classes" is because those files can be auto generated (if you wish) by Xcode's Data Model Editor. For example, you can simply delete an NSManagedObject's .h and .m files, and regenerate them. If you made any changes to those .h or .m files, those changes would obviously be lost when the files are regenerated. If you really want to go this route, simply avoid regenerating files for this particular class, and manage it manually. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yep, that part I knew. The books, tutorials, etc. shouldn't strictly say "don't touch" but instead say "auto-generate, you can edit and add methods but if you choose to auto-generate again, your changes won't be saved."